# Can I use JavaFX 2.x for my App without distributing the source code?

Tags: java, licensing, javafx-2, javafx

Just started an app using java and the plan was to use JavaFX. But then I saw the JavaFX license in wikipedia -  GPL v2. I'm not good with licenses but from what I understand if I plan on using JavaFX I have to distribute the code along with the app. Am I on the right track?

The application will have Networking involved so allowing source code access to clients is unacceptable.

Comment: A language implementation (compiler, interpreter) can be under the GPL license without burdening the programs written in this language or compiled with this tool with this license (unless otherwise specified, of course). What is important too is the license of the libraries shipped with the language...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Oracle's website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#10):

> **10. What type of license is JavaFX available under?**
>   JavaFX is available under the [same license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html) and business model as Java SE. This includes the ability for third party developers to distribute the runtime librairies with their application(s), subject to the terms and conditions of the license.